# How do I pass props with the cart props. So that my sidebar toggles

Tags: reactjs

The code is taking some props and requires the prop to toggle the side. However, when I pass in the cart props the toggle no longer functions.

```
const Toolbar = ({currentUser, hidden, signOutStart}, props) => {
    return (
        <header className='toolbar'>
            <nav className='toolbar_navigation'>
                <div className="toolbar_toggle-button">
                    <DrawerToggleButton click={this.props.handleDrawerToggleClick}/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), so you wouldn't use `this` to access props. `this.props` or similar would be when you are working with a class component. "props" are passed as the first argument to functional components, and there usually wouldn't be a second argument of "props" if you are rendering the component in a normal way. Instead add `handleDrawerToggleClick` to props you are already destructuring in your first argument:

```
const Toolbar = ({ currentUser, hidden, signOutStart, handleDrawerToggleClick }) => {
    return (
        <header className='toolbar'>
            <nav className='toolbar_navigation'>
                <div className="toolbar_toggle-button">
                    <DrawerToggleButton click={handleDrawerToggleClick} />
                </div>
```

Hopefully that helps!